# PHP - trim array elements value without foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I am using following code in php:
Code:

```
$input = array("     text1","text2      "," text3       ","     text4");
$output = array();
foreach($input as $val)
     {
        $output[] = trim($val);
     }
var_dump($output);
```

Is it possible to trim array elements value without foreach loop?

Comment: No. trim accepts only strings as its argument. One way or another, you're going to have to loop over the array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [**`array_map`**](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```
$output = array_map('trim', $input);
```

Of course this will still iterate over the array internally.

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine;

```
$input = array("     text1","text2      "," text3       ","     text4");
$output = array_map('trim', $input);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Nice transition from `array_walk` to `array_map` ;)

Answer (score 1):

use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for apply a function to each element

```
$input = array_map('trim', $input);
```